How to get log output from ansible-navigator run in gitlab pipeline?
I have a simple gitlab pipeline defined as such:
deploy-to-live:
  image: <custom image> # preloaded with ansible-navigator
  stage: deploy
  script: >-
    ansible-navigator run
    10_base.yml
    -i inventories/live

When running this playbook, I get the following message
$ ansible-navigator run 10_base.yml -i inventories/live
Running the command: docker pull <custom image>:latest
the input device is not a TTY
Please review the log for errors.

I saw several mentions of this error message, all advising me to drop the -it option from my docker call. Which sounds reasonable enough, but I'm not actually setting that, ansible-navigator seems to. I know I can specify container options with --container-options, but that does not allow be to remove options.
How can I remove this error message and still see the log output of ansible-navigator in the gitlab job, just like I would on the local command line?

It looks like there's some misunderstanding here.
First of all, ansible-navigator is a text-based user interface so I'm not sure why would one use it in a CI/CD environment.
Next, it already runs itself in an execution environment by default - which is another container - so most likely it won't work by default when you wrap the GitHub stage into your own custom image.
Finally, the -it CLI flags refer to Docker interactive + TTY mode, whereas ansible-navigator has its own interactive output mode (enabled by default since it's a UI) that should be changed to stdout output mode in order to have the logs only.
To sum up, I see several options to resolve your issue:

If your container already has the proper dependencies, continue using ansible-navigator but:

disable running its own execution environment;
enable its stdout mode instead the interactive one:

deploy-to-live:
  image: <custom image>
  stage: deploy
  script: >-
    ansible-navigator run 10_base.yml
      -i inventories/live
      --execution-environment false
      --mode stdout          


Continue using ansible-navigator but:

remove the image wrapper;
set your own execution environment image in its settings file:

execution-environment:
  enabled: True      
  image: <custom_image>


enable the stdout mode instead the interactive one:

deploy-to-live:
  stage: deploy
  script: >-
    ansible-navigator run 10_base.yml
      -i inventories/live
      --mode stdout          


Use the standard ansible-playbook
within a container that has Ansible and the required dependencies (in other words - an
execution environment container):
deploy-to-live:
  image: <custom image with Ansible and dependencies>
  stage: deploy
  script: >-
    ansible-playbook 10_base.yml
      -i inventories/live



For more details, check out ansible-navigator readme on GitHub and configuration reference.

I would like to avoid #1 because I think it sensible to use EEs, especially to enable developers to run the exact same setup on their own machines.
#2 and #3 do not seem to work, I get the following error: "ERROR! the playbook: /10_base.yml could not be found".

So far we've been using ansible-navigator for development and manual deployment and found it and the ansible EEs really useful. I am currently tasked with transfering this to an automated workflow, so my first idea was to simply replicate what we're doing in a gitlab pipeline. If ansible-navigator is not meant to be used that way, how would one use ansible EEs in production? I can't seem to find anything on that in github or on readthedocs.

In #1 you can use the same EE image. And in any case, you should make sure that your playbook is accessible - you did not specify if it's already part of your EE, or you get it from Git during the previous stage. I'm the latter case you likely need to mount it into the container. As for EEs in general - I might be forgetting something but AFAIK they're not popular because some time ago the ansible-runner container has been deprecated, the community switched over to building own images, and now we have so called EE requiring more efforts to migrate to than to create own image.

Meanwhile, in #1 I talked about the default EE that ansible-navigator uses, and assumed you want to use your <custom image> as the EE. You need to select one option - as of now you're trying to run a container from within another container.

Yes, I'm trying to run a container from within another container - but isn't that exactly what DinD is for?

Am I understanding you right that there is no sensible way to integrate Ansible EEs into e.g. a gitlab pipeline?
The appeal of it, especially ansible-builder, was to have a more structured and concise way of defining the environment for ansible to run in. I've found an execution-environment.yml much easier to read and maintain than a Dockerfile. But if there is no good way of actually using them, I'm not sure there is a point to it.

I don't see a reason of using another container of you already have an EE one prepared. You can just let the ansible-navigator do its work and run the EE that you defined in its settings.
